# Why the service --status-all is not listing this working service?

Tags: command-line, bash, systemd, services

I am absolute not into Linux system administration (I am a software developer) and I have the following question for you about services.

On an **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** machine there is installed a software as service. I mean that I can run it performing this statment in the shell:

```
sudo service wso2ei start
```

and I have the service configuration file into:

```
/etc/systemd/system/wso2ei.service
```

that contains something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=WSO2EI

After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0
User=root
Group=nogroup
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/jdk/jdk1.8.0_192
Environment=CARBON_HOME=/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

ExecStart=/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/bin/integrator.sh
ExecStop=/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/integrator.sh stop

#TimeoutSec=130

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

it is working fine and I can start and stop the service by the following statments:

```
sudo service wso2ei start
```

and

```
sudo service wso2ei stopt
```

So this service is working fine...but...I tried to list all the services by this stament:

```
service --status-all
```

I expected to find my **wso2ei** service into the output list but there isn't !!!

This is my output:

```
$ sudo service --status-all
 [ - ]  acpid
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  atd
 [ + ]  cntlm
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cryptdisks
 [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  ebtables
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  iscsid
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ + ]  lvm2-lvmetad
 [ + ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  lxcfs
 [ - ]  lxd
 [ - ]  mdadm
 [ - ]  mdadm-waitidle
 [ - ]  ntp
 [ - ]  open-iscsi
 [ - ]  open-vm-tools
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  screen-cleanup
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ + ]  udev
 [ - ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
$
```

Why my **wso2ei** is not in this list? What is wrong? What am I missing?

Moreover: if I check the status of this particular service I obtain this output:

```
$ sudo service wso2ei status
● wso2ei.service - WSO2EI
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wso2ei.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-10-11 21:03:06 CEST; 1 day 22h ago
  Process: 56854 ExecStop=/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/integrator.sh stop (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 56912 (integrator.sh)
    Tasks: 179 (limit: 9486)
   CGroup: /system.slice/wso2ei.service
           ├─56912 /bin/sh /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/bin/integrator.sh
           └─56958 /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/jdk/jdk1.8.0_192/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -X
```

So I think that the **service** statment find the **wso2ei** service in some way.

I think that I am missing something...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the manpage

```
service --status-all
```

shows

> ```
> service --status-all runs all init scripts, in alphabetical order,
> with the status command. The status is [ + ] for running services,
> [ - ] for stopped services and [ ? ] for services without a
> status command.  This option only calls  status for sysvinit jobs.
> ```

```
ls -al /etc/init.d/
```

There can you see the listed services from sysvinit system.

You wrote an systemd unit, they can be listed with:

```bash
systemctl list-units     # for currently active units
systemctl -a list-units  # for all known units
```

Add the `--user` flag to these commands if you want to list the current user’s units instead of the system ones.

Comment: The key for me was distinguishing between sysvinit ("legacy"?) jobs and systemd units. Thanks!